# Stacked Divs Max Width of Parent

Tags: html, css

I have a flexbox that acts as a container for stack of divs that are layered on top of each other. This div has a height, width, min-height & min-width set.

The issue is one or more "layer" divs could contain a background image that is larger than the set dimensions of the container.

Because I have the position set to absolute on the layer images it expands outside of the parent div bounds.

I am looking for a solution where I do not need to set the height & width on the layer divs. Is there one?

```css
    .stack-container {
        height: 800px;
        min-height: 400px;
        width: 1000px;
        min-width: 600px;
    }
    .layer {
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<div class="stack-container">
       <div class="layer"></div>
       <div class="layer"></div>
       <div class="layer"></div>
       <div class="layer"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try this, `.stack-container .layer {
   width: 100%;
}` and convert `min` to `max`

Comment: you are missing  `position:relative;` on `.stack-container` to make it work

Comment: I need something like max-width otherwise it expands divs that are smaller than the parent div which is also undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Set `width: 100%` on your layer class, it'll adjust itself to the current width of the parent element.

```css
.stack-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 1000px;
  min-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack-container">
   <div class="layer" style="width: 1100px;">test</div>
   <div class="layer" style="width: 2100px;">test</div>
   <div class="layer" style="width: 5000px;">test</div>
   <div class="layer" style="width: 10000px;">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works if I also set the height, but I'm back to the same issue is I don't always want the layer div's at full with. Only if they are larger than the container, but max height and width don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: For that, use `overflow: hidden` on the parent class. See my update.